# What is the value of $\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}} q^p$?

Tags: number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

I wonder what is the value of $$\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}} q^p$$

where $p$ is taking values in primes and $0<q<1$?

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly there is no closed form for this.

Comment: Indeed. For example, when $q=1/2$ this is sometimes called the 'prime constant', as it encodes the positions of the primes in binary. There seems to be little known about it. See https://oeis.org/A051006

Comment: This diverges as q approaches 1. Do you mean for what c does it approach c/(q-1)?

Comment: @ThomasBloom well I need the behavior of this function at $q\to1$

Comment: @ThomasBloom I need the properties of the pole/singularity.

Comment: @ThomasBloom like what function of q it behaves near 1

Comment: I see, I don't know off hand if this is possible, but I suggest editing the question/asking a new question being more explicit that this is what you want, since this is not clear from the question as written.